# How to predict product reaction using rdkit?

Tags: python, rdkit

how to predict product chemical reaction using rdkit, this is my `code`:

```
disodium_tetraborat = Chem.MolFromSmiles('B1(OB2OB(OB(O1)O2)[O-])[O-]')
kanamycin = Chem.MolFromSmiles('C1C(C(C(C(C1N)OC2C(C(C(C(O2)CN)O)O)O)O)OC3C(C(C(C(O3)CO)O)N)O)N')
rxn_smarts = '[NH2:1][C:2](=[S:3])[NH0:4].[C:5](=[O:6])[C:7][Cl:8]>>[N:4][c:2]1[s:3][c:5][c:7][n:1]1'
rxn = AllChem.ReactionFromSmarts(rxn_smarts)
product = rxn.RunReactants((disodium_tetraborat, kanamycin))[0][0]
Chem.SanitizeMol(product)
```

`error` that i am getting:

```
IndexError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-eda85f568910> in <module>
      3 rxn_smarts = '[NH2:1][C:2](=[S:3])[NH0:4].[C:5](=[O:6])[C:7][Cl:8]>>[N:4][c:2]1[s:3][c:5][c:7][n:1]1'
      4 rxn = AllChem.ReactionFromSmarts(rxn_smarts)
----> 5 product = rxn.RunReactants((disodium_tetraborat, kanamycin))[0][0]
      6 Chem.SanitizeMol(product)

IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

how to solve it ? thank you.

Comment: What is the value of ```rxn.RunReactants((disodium_tetraborat, kanamycin))```?

Answer (score 0):

you get an error because the reaction doesn't go through, and the products tuple is empty. The reaction you defined in rxn is unrelated to your reagents, it's a cyclization of a thiourea with a alpha halo carbonyl to form an aminothiazole. But your reagents don't satisfy those criteria.
Here's a codeblock with reagents that do satisfy those criteria:

```
reagent1 = Chem.MolFromSmiles('NC(=S)N(C)C')
reagent2 = Chem.MolFromSmiles('[Cl]CC(=O)c1ccccc1')
rxn_smarts = '[NH2:1][C:2](=[S:3])[NH0:4].[C:5](=[O:6])[C:7][Cl:8]>>[N:4][c:2]1[s:3][c:5][c:7][n:1]1'
rxn = AllChem.ReactionFromSmarts(rxn_smarts)
product = rxn.RunReactants((reagent1,reagent2))[0][0]
Chem.SanitizeMol(product)
```

this results in the product `CN(C)c1ncc(-c2ccccc2)s1`